# Trouble installling SRILM on mac (Mohave)

Tags: macos, kaldi, srilm

In order to use KALDI ASR system I am trying to install SRILM (1.7.2) (Mac computer with Mohave 10.14.2). Apparently everything goes fine during SRILM compilation (make World), but in the end I get various errors when I try to pass the tests in SRILM (make tests). We have found that in machines in which SRILM tests fail, the accuracy of KALDI is variable (WER differ between two identical executions; e.g. 50% to 60%).

The two problems (failing to pass SRILM tests and variability in Kaldi) occur in Mac, but not in Linux (also in Linux installed in a Windows virtual machine)

I changed this in *srilm/common/Makefile.machine.macosx*:

```
CC = cc $(GCC_FLAGS)<BR>
CXX = c++ $(GCC_FLAGS) -DINSTANTIATE_TEMPLATES<BR>
```

to

```
CC = clang $(GCC_FLAGS)<BR>
CXX = clang++ $(GCC_FLAGS) -DINSTANTIATE_TEMPLATES<BR>
```

I also tried adding this line to the same file:

```
GCC_FLAGS += -m64<BR>
```

Finally, I tried different versions of SRILM

None of that worked

Any advice?

I have seen that Kaldi can be used with IRSTLM instead of SRILM. However, I'd prefer to use SRILM if it is possible
. 
Thanks! 
Ignacio

Comment: it might be corrupted memory on that machine.

Comment: I have found the same problem in three different MAC computers (one MacPro and  two iMAC)

Comment: Ok, well, you need to be more specific on which tests fail and how do they fail exactly.

Comment: Thanks @NikolayShmyrev.  There are 17 tests (of 74) with errors (i.e.  DIFF in STDOUT or STDERR)
TEST      STDOUT  STDERR<BR>
class-ngram  DIF  OK<BR>
class-ngram-simple DIF OK<BR>
make-unigram-pfsg  DIF OK<BR>
nbest-rescore DIF DIF<BR>
nbest-rover DIF OK<BR>
nbest-rover-acoustic DIF OK<BR>
nbest-rover-posteriors DIF OK
ngram-count-abs DIF DIF
ngram-count-gt OK DIF
ngram-count-gt-novocab OK DIF
ngram-count-maxent DIF OK
ngram-count-wb-floats DIF DIF
ngram-interpolate DIF OK
ngram-interpolate-static DIF OK
ngram-rescore DIF OK
lattice-expansion-ppl DIF OK
select-vocab DIF OK